# java packages - access root package from subfolder

Tags: java

I have a question here. Suppose I have two below directories:

```
fruit/apple.java

fruit/mango/mango.java
```

With packages, I can make apple.java access mango.java with import mango.* (package mango created in mango.java)

But how do I do it opposite. For example mango.java needs to go to root directory and access apple.java (variables).

I am trying to learn packages, but it seems that I am getting confused.

Thanks.

Comment: so just import fruit.apple

Comment: Your package hierarchy should be the same as your folder structure, so you would have something like `package fruit.mango;` and `import fruit.mango.Mango;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about what `import` means.

Start by learning and following the Java coding standards.  Your class names should begin with a capital letter: `Apple.java` and `Mango.java`.  It'll make your code readable by other Java developers.

As for access, either class just has to obtain an instance of the class it wants:

```
package fruit;

public class Apple {
    private Mango mango;

    public Apple() {
        this.mango = new Mango();
    }
}
```

Import only makes it possible for you to use the short class name; e.g. `Mango` instead of `fruit.Mango`.   There's no class loading or granting of access going on.  It only saves you keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the apple in your mango class via...

```
import fruit.apple;
```

You should also upper case those class names i.e. Apple and Mango.

So...

```
import fruit.Apple;
```

You should probably have a Mango in the same package as an Apple, I would have thought though rather than in a separate fruit.mango package.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the apple in your mango class

```
import fruit.apple;
```

if you are in a IDE like eclipse this can be done with the context menu.

[image]